# How can I read the headers from a WinNT portable executable file using Perl?

Tags: perl, portable-executable

I want to work with PE files in Perl and didn't find a module, so I think I will write my own (already did that in delphi once).

I only got one problem, when mapping the executable to a buffer, how can i search for octals like 0x00004550 (IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE), convert them back to writeable strings etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There *is* a Perl module to manipulate portable executables:  [`Win32::Exe`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32::Exe).

I don't have a clue on your exact question, but if you still want to write your own library, `Win32::Exe` might be a good reference.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Win32::Exe and `objdump` now :)

Answer (score 2):

For converting that value to a bytestring representation, use `pack`. The constant you are dealing is a little-endian 32 bit value, so 'V' in the template.

```
$ perl -e 'print pack q[V], 0x00004550' | hd
00000000  50 45 00 00                                       |PE..|
00000004
```

See `perldoc -f pack` for details.

You probably won't need to search for strings like "PE\0\0", just use them to verify whether the file you are reading actually is a PE file. The 'PE' section usually comes right after the DOS ('MZ') section which has its own length field.

(I agree that `Win32::Exe` may be worth a look, depending on what you want to do.)