# Perl: Get minimum supported operating system for a binary

Tags: windows, perl, version, portable-executable, subsystem

Is there a Perl command that lets me get the minimum supported OS for any given binary?

You can manually get that information by running "link /dump /headers [binaryFile]" and looking for the "subsystem version" link.  I don't want to use that since it's got really bad perf.

Thanks

Comment: Erm, since Perl is an interpreted language, what do you mean by a "binary in Perl"?  Do you mean a Perl program packaged together with the interpreter via something like PAR::Packer (http://search.cpan.org/~rschupp/PAR-Packer-1.010/lib/PAR/Packer.pm)?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Question updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need this for Windows, use [get_manifest](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aExe#get_manifest) from [Win32::Exe](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aExe). You will need to install it first.

Comment: +1; See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418855/how-can-i-read-the-headers-from-a-winnt-portable-executable-file-using-perl

Answer (score 3):

If there's a command that gets what you want, why not just run that command?

You can use [backticks or qx//](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx/STRING/) in Perl to get a command's output

eg:

```
my $output = `command arg1 arg2 ...`;
```

Or, if you want an array of lines:

```
my @lines = `command arg1 arg2 ...`;
```

Then you can use Perl's normal facilities for scanning that output for patterns you're interested in.

<s>Also, your command looks like it is for Windows - is that true? If so, you should add a Windows tag.</s>

Comment: I tried out the link command but the perf was really bad, which is why I'm looking for an alternative